# Find the shortest distance between point $(2,0)$ and function $\sqrt{16x^2 + 5x+16}$.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I want to find the shortest distance between point $(2,0)$ and function $\sqrt{16x^2 + 5x+16}$, So I did the optimization but the answer is always wrong.

$$\begin{align}D=&\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y)^2}\\ y^2=&{16x^2 + 5x+16}\\ &\text{(by substituting)}\\ D=&\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(16x^2 + 5x+16)}\\ D=& \sqrt{17{x}^{2}+ x + 20}\\ &\text{(Convert to a polynomial since root doesn't matter in the domain)}\\ D(x)=& 17x^2+x+20 \\ D^\prime(x)=& 34x+1 \\ x =& \frac{-1}{34}\end{align}$$

Which is clearly not the closest point, So what did I do wrong?

Here is the question and my answer, which is evaluated as wrong.
[image]

Comment: I was wrong, it actually looks strange :)

Comment: Have you substituted $x$ into $D$ to find the distance?

Comment: @amWhy Yes I did, I assumed that my answer was wrong after I looked at a plot which didn't really convince me that the closest point is at $\frac{-1}{34}$

Comment: Should the path to the closest point be perpendicular to the tangent line or does this apply only for straight lines?

Comment: I'm wondering about your decision to to equate $D(x) = \sqrt{17x^2+ x + 20}$ to $D(x) = 17x^2 + x + 20 = (D(x))^2$? You should have $(D(x))^2 = 17x^2 + x + 20?$

Comment: Oh, This is probably the mistake I did, but how should this affect my result?

Comment: Should I differentiate $(D(x))^2$ getting $2D(x)$ then divide both sides by 2? I am not sure what should be done here.

Comment: Should be using the expression that gives you the actual distance, not the expression that gives you the $y$-coordinate.

Comment: @tilper I did use it, I updated the question, There is an image showing the question and my answer.

Comment: @OmarAhmad you updated the 34 vs 43 but you're still using the expression for the $y$-coordinate.  See my comment on the answer where we were also discussing.

Comment: @tilper Ah, damn , Sorry about that, So the correct answer is substituting in D.

Comment: What you have entered is the $y$-value of the closest point, not the distance from the point to $(2,0)$.

Comment: I can't apply for the quiz again now, will have to wait for couple of hours to apply and check, Anyway thanks for your help.
Marking @Sil 's answer as correct because plotting is what made me think my answer was wrong (aside from my answer being actually wrong).

Comment: so, what was the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct. The confusion is caused by the software you use to vizualize the graph - they do scale the axis differently AND they hide values of $y$ (see some graphs below for omitted values between $0$ and $3$).

**Maple (even with 1:1 ratio checked, values hidden on $y$ axis):**

[image]

**Google: (all $y$ values shown, but scale is different)**

[image]

**Mathematica (with AspectRatio->1, again missing values on $y$ axis)**

[image]

You need to be careful about this and setup tools properly. Here is for example Geogebra which is using 1:1 scale by default and does not hide any values from the plot since you see whole canvas (https://www.geogebra.org/graphing). You can see that your result now makes sense visually.

[image]

Comment: Ok, but when i insert the result I got in the quiz it get evaluated as wrong, May be it has something with the power 2 (look at the question's comments).

Comment: What are you inserting where?

Comment: Quiz on Optimization on Coursera, Calculus One course.

Comment: Well based on your updated question, you are inserting function value, not the distance value.

Comment: Maple should give a better plot with the "scaling=constrained" option.

Comment: @tilper This one is actually with the "scaling=constrained" ... I am using `plot(sqrt(16*x^2+5*x+16),x=-1..2,scaling=constrained);` .

Comment: @Sil, weird, not sure I've ever seen that not work.  I'd probably also try $y=3..6$.  Won't be near my comp for a couple more hours.

Comment: @tilper Oh I see whats going on, the scale is correct in this case, but just the $y$ axis is plotted from the minimal value of the function, not from 0. Plotting with y=0..9 seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

We can minimize $(x-2)^2+y^2$ for convenience, since squaring is increasing on positive reals. Then as you substituted
$$
f(x)=(x-2)^2+16x^2+5x+16\Rightarrow f(x)=17x^2+x+20\Rightarrow f'(x)=34x+1=0\Rightarrow x=-\frac{1}{34}
$$
As you found. Making the closest point on the curve 
$$
(-\frac{1}{34},\sqrt{16(1/34)^2-5/34+16})\sim (-.03,3.99)
$$
What's the problem?

Comment: And the distance should be somewhere close to 3.98, but the quiz I am taking evaluate this as a wrong answer.

Comment: @OmarAhmad, try giving an exact answer instead of an approximate one.  e.g. $\sqrt 2$ and not $1.414$ etc.

Comment: @tilper Actually we insert the formula itself not numbers, so it is not about perception.

Comment: @OmarAhmad insert what formula?  I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @tilper I mean that we enter $\sqrt{16(1/34)^2-5/43+16}$ instead of 1.98... or the simplified version.

Comment: @OmarAhmad ah, got it.  Aren't you supposed to give the distance though?  So you should be using $\sqrt{17x^2 + x +20}$.